# Introductory/Beginner books on Buddhism, but for children

Tags: books, learning, learning-materials, children

There are a few posts on the site asking for good introduction/beginner books on Buddhism, but I can't seem to find any that a child could read and understand.

Although age range doesn't really matter to the answer that people might post, let's say someone between the age of 7 and 14, just to have some context.

Comment: Good post on teaching children: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/7279/151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reading adult and young adult books by the age of 14.

I haven't read [this one](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/294533/buddhist-scriptures-by-anonymous/) in particular but *Penguin Classics* tend to be alright as a pseudo-scholarly introduction to a reader who is otherwise naive about the subject.

I'm pretty sure I read the Penguin Classic edition of the *[Dhammapada](https://www.penguin.co.uk/books/354/35496/the-dhammapada/9780140449419.html)* at one stage.

I guess the classic introduction to Buddhism is the story of Gautama's meeting the "four divine messengers" and leaving home, becoming enlightened -- see for example [Meeting the Divine Messengers](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/bps-essay_32.html).

I think that story is published in innumerable editions and translations, some wth more and some with less attempt to make the story seem realistic (as opposed to e.g. supernatural, viz the Buddha's remarkable powers and Mara etc). Canonically I think that story is the introduction to the Jataka.

I haven't seen the Gathas in an edition for children, it might be an interesting suggestion though -- perhaps something to read together and discuss?

The commentary to the Dhammapada consists of stories (including the supernatural), one per verse (and many verses), see e.g. [Buddhist Stories from the Dhammapada Commentary](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/burlingame/wheel324.html) -- the stories are included in [this online edition](https://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/) (click on the links to each verse e.g. [Verse 1](https://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=001)) I'd guess there might be a for-children edition of that.

A Google search for [Buddhist school books](https://www.google.com/search?q=buddhist+school+books) might be useful, for example my first result from that search was this page: [Buddhist Studies for Schools: eBook Library (PDF documents)](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/ebooks.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The Buddha provided a teaching to his 7 year old son, which instructed two things, namely:

1. To never tell a deliberate lie.
2. To always reflect (think; consider) about whether an action to be performed or performed harms oneself or another.

This teaching is called: [Advice to Rāhula at Ambalaṭṭhika](https://suttacentral.net/mn61/en/sujato).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a title for you but there are the Jataka Tales which would introduce some Buddhist ideas to entertain and there are english publications of these.

However if the child is over 7 years old it is possible that they would understand whatever you throw at them in regards to the Dhamma, there are mentions of very young Arahants from the time of the Buddha.

Other than that there are the Gathas (poems of the Elders) which come to mind if you are looking for something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Please check book at below link :

- [The Story of Buddha : The Enlightened One (Tripti Nainwal, Ayeshe Sadr, Ishaan Dasgupta)](https://dl.flipkart.com/dl/story-buddha-enlightened-one/p/itmfgfc3tnrhdhp5?pid=9789386887085&cmpid=product.share.pp)

Above book is specifically designed for children.Flowing visuals combined with painstaking details and merge seamlessly with  strong contemporary narrative. 
 Read at above link about book description.

(If above link doesn't work ,check this [link](https://www.flipkart.com/story-buddha-enlightened-one/p/itmfgfc3tnrhdhp5?pid=9789386887085&lid=LSTBOK9789386887085LUYGX0&marketplace=FLIPKART&cmpid=content_book_8965229628_gmc_pla&tgi=sem,1,G,11214002,g,search,,291072750917,1o3,,,m,,mobile,,,,,&ef_id=Cj0KCQjwr-_tBRCMARIsAN413WRe_-SkEC78PlvqA84nSEc9HVbfh61oVJHz2MWqsU2ZdzgE7ZslH5YaAg3yEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!739!3!291072750917!!!g!295092701166!&gclid=Cj0KCQjwr-_tBRCMARIsAN413WRe_-SkEC78PlvqA84nSEc9HVbfh61oVJHz2MWqsU2ZdzgE7ZslH5YaAg3yEALw_wcB%0A), taken from my web-browser).